# The result of a SQL query never return null;

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
var AreaCode = CID;

IQueryable<Center> results = _context.Center.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM Center WHERE CenterID={0} AND Displayable=1", AreaCode );

if (results == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("NoCenter");
}

return View(await results.ToListAsync());
```

I have this code and found that the `results` of the query never returns null when it should for some reason. I deliberately set the `AreaCode` to a value that matches no row, and yet still I still have the same issue.

Any guru help please!

Comment: since you are getting a list, its empty. it will not be `null`

Comment: I wouldn't redirect to another action - this is a view level concern.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking queryable. It is not data, it is just an expression and never null. Try this

```
var  results = await _context.Center.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM Center WHERE CenterID={0} AND Displayable=1", AreaCode )
.ToListAsync();

if (results != null && results.Count > 0)
{
   return View(results);
}

return RedirectToAction("NoCenter");
```

Comment: invoking `ToList()` will still be and empty list and not `null`

Answer (score 0):

since you are getting a list, its empty. it will not be null

you can do this

```
var  results = await _context.Center.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM Center WHERE CenterID={0} AND Displayable=1", AreaCode )
.ToListAsync();

if (results.Any()==false)
{
    return RedirectToAction("NoCenter");
}
return View(results);
```

Comment: `==false` is just silly, how about `!results.Any()`

Comment: @Charlieface, both are the same. i wrote explicitly so anyone reading this can understand clearly. sometimes the fast readers tend to not notice the negation (`!`)